# How does a Powershell cmdlet work?

Tags: powershell, scripting

Specifically I need to know how the **Restart-Service** cmdlet works.
For e.g when I'm writing

```
Restart-Service myservice1, myservice2
```

I want to know how it flows.
Does it stop both services before restarting them or does it restart them one by one?

Generally speaking is there anyway to see the coding inside a cmdlet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try looking into the module library using something like [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). For that cmdlet the source is viewable(at least dotPeek's version of it. I'm not a programmer, so I don't know if that's 100% correct code). At least it shows that it stops a service, then starts it, in a foreach loop. I'm not going to post the code as I don't know how legal that is. :)

You could also look in the documentation provided on Microsoft Technet.

> The Restart-Service cmdlet is designed to **stop and then restart** the
>   specified service. (If the service is **already stopped**, well, that’s
>   OK: in that case **Restart-Service will simply start** the service.) This
>   is a particularly useful cmdlet for services that have memory leaks
>   and periodically need to be stopped and then restarted;
>   Restart-Service can take care of both of those functions with a single
>   command.

[Source: Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176942.aspx)

Comment: Yes!! dotPeek nails it! Thanks for the suggestion @Graimer.

Answer (score 0):

Always good to read documentation, but as usual, YMMV. Imprecise language gets slippery real quick, and bad assumptions are no fun. While i'm being preachy, the devil is in the details.

So a test never hurts. You might try running `get-wmiObject win32_service` while restart-service does its thing in another window. Gwmi only because get-service might be too slow. Probably overkill, but the test seems poshable in a single script, maybe with start-job and get-date.